# iOS UIBuilder setting CustomClass for tablecell - why

Tags: ios, xcode, tablecell

Why should I set a Custom-class for a Cell within the UIBuilder? All examples I can find are setting the Identifier and use this on in `...cellForRowAtIndexPath:...`?

Is this useless here?

---

Edit:

Sorry, I think, this was not asked clearly - so I'll try again:

- Normally (all found examples) the Cell-Identifier (in the attributes inspector) is set an this ID is used in the `...cellForRowAtIndexPath:...`-method to identify, which Class should be used.
- Beside the Cell-Identifier (attributes inpector), there is the the possibility to set the custom class (identity inspector). **When will I use this setting in the context of table-cells?**

Comment: Can you rephrase your question or go more into depth about what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: one reason would be to be able to drag outlets if you use custom cells

Comment: Updated my question. I hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Custom Cells in the Interface Builder, you can easily manipulate the appearance of your custom cell, and make it have custom properties and behave in specific ways which is very effective.

Custom Class is used whenever you make your own class for a UITableViewCell.

```
#import "UITableViewCell.h"

@interface MyCell : UITableViewCell

@property NSString *myCustomProperty;

@end
```

Then in the code, you can access the custom properties of your cell by doing something like:

```
MyCell *cell = (MyCell*)[tableView objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[cell setMyCustomProperty:@"Custom Cells Yey!"];
```

Also, may I also note that the identifiers are primarily used to manage memory effectively in UITableViews. The table views use trickery in their implementation to cache the cells rather than create new cells every time you scroll a little bit otherwise that would be overkill so you can use identifiers to cache rows in the tableview automagically.

Comment: Yes that help. I misunderstood something I read some days ago...  Got it now: you use the Identifier **and** Class if you need an own implementation. Thx

Comment: Exactly :) Identifiers are not used for a custom implementation. I'll edit my post a little further.